# Finding the volume of a pseudosphere that has been parametrised in $\theta$ and $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I've got a problem calculating the volume of the top half of a pseudosphere.

> The pseudosphere is parametrised by
>
> $$\Phi(t,\theta) = \Big ( \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\cosh(t)}, \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cosh(t)}, t-\tanh(t)\Big)$$
>   with $0\le t$ and $0\le \theta \lt 2\pi$
>
> So the volume I'm trying to find is that between the $x-y$ axis and the surface of the inside of the pseudosphere. Now, we've been given that the formula for any region $V$ in $\mathbb R^3$ is
>   $$\iiint_V r\tanh^2(t) \ \mathrm dr \ \mathrm d\theta \ \mathrm d t$$ based on the change of variables $x = r\cos(\theta) \ , \ y = r\sin(\theta) \ $and $ z = t - \tanh(t)$

Since $t\ge 0$ we have $0 \lt r \le 1$ because when $t=0$ is put into $x = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\cosh(t)}$ we get $x=\cos(\theta)$ and similarly when $t=0$ is put into y = $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cosh(t)}$ we get $y = \sin(\theta)$

Then, $$x^2 + y^2 = \cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) = 1$$ so the radius at $t=0$ is $1$, and as $t \to \infty$ we get $\cosh(t) \to \infty$ so both $x$ and $y$ approach $0$ so the radius approaches $0$.

So the integral becomes

$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta = 2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{r=1} r\tanh^2(t) \ \mathrm dr \ \mathrm d\theta \ \mathrm d t$$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} \tanh^2(t) \ \mathrm d t$$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} 1-\text{sech}^2(t) \ \mathrm d t $$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty} \Bigg [ t - \tanh(t)\Bigg]_{t=0}^{t=b}$$

which does not converge.

I got close by multiplying the inside of the integral by $$\lvert \vec T_t \times \vec T_\theta \rvert = \frac{\sinh(t)}{\cosh^2(t)}$$ so the integral becomes

$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta = 2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{r=1} r\tanh^2(t)\frac{\sinh(t)}{\cosh^2(t)} \ \mathrm dr \ \mathrm d\theta \ \mathrm d t$$

$$ = \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta = 2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{r=1} r\frac{\sinh^3(t)}{\cosh^4(t)} \ \mathrm dr \ \mathrm d\theta \ \mathrm d t$$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} \frac{\sinh(t)\sinh^2(t)}{\cosh^4(t)}  \ \mathrm d t$$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{t=0}^{t=b} \frac{\sinh(t)(\cosh^2(t)-1)}{\cosh^4(t)}  \ \mathrm d t$$

make a u-sub: $$u = \cosh(t) \implies \mathrm du = \sinh(t) \mathrm dt$$
with $ u(b) = \cosh(b)$ and $u(0) = 1$

so the integral becomes
$$ \pi \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{u=1}^{u=\cosh(b)} \frac{u^2-1}{u^4}  \ \mathrm d u $$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty} \Bigg [ \frac{-1}{u} + \frac{1}{3u^3}\Bigg]_{u=1}^{u=\cosh(b)}$$

$$ = \pi \lim_{b \to \infty} \Bigg [ -\frac{1}{\cosh(b)} + \frac{1}{3\cosh^3(b)} +1 - \frac{1}{3}\Bigg ]$$

$$ = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

Which I believe is double the correct answer of $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Can anyone help if possible?

Cheers heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in the change of variable. The new variables
$$ x=r\cos \theta, \quad y=r\sin\theta, \quad z = t-\tanh t$$
are not suitable for this question.

Take instead the transformation
$$ x=\frac{r\cos \theta}{\cosh t}, \quad y=\frac{r\sin\theta}{\cosh t}, \quad z = t-\tanh t.
$$
The Jacobian is $r\tanh^2 t \,\mathrm{sech}^2 t$. Hence the integral becomes
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{t=0}^{t=\infty} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta= 2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=1} &r \tanh^2 t \,\mathrm{sech}^2 t\, dr\, d\theta\, dt \\
&= \left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1}r \,dr\right)\left(\int_0^\infty \tanh^2 t\,\mathrm{sech}^2 t\,dt\right)\\
&= \pi \left[\frac{\tanh^3 t}{3}\right]_0^\infty \\
&= \frac{\pi}{3},
\end{align*}
$$
which is the correct answer.

Comment: sorry buddy $1-\mathrm{sech}^2(t) $ does actually equal $\tanh^2(t)$, but I see what you mean about the potential mistake in the change of variables (the new change of variables and the triple integral for any region in $\mathbf V$ was given in the question and I think they made an error with the change of variables). Thanks anyway man appreciate the help

Comment: @Jackyune No need to apologize, because you're totally right! $1-\mathrm{sech}^2 t$ is indeed equal to $\tanh^2 t$, and I didn't see that. I'll fix it in the answer. You're welcome, and thank you for the constructive comment.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudosphere is generated by rotating a [tractrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix) about its asymptote. Suppose the *x*-axis is the asymptote, and the tractrix starts at $(0,1)$.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$

$y^2dx=(1-y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}dy=-y\sqrt{1-y^2}dy$

$\text{Volume}=\pi\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}{y^2dx}=\pi\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}{(-y\sqrt{1-y^2})dy}=\pi\int_{y=0}^{y=1}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}dy}=\frac{\pi}{3}$